# App crashing on pinch in-out map

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview

I am using MKMapKit for map. I am adding annotation and even providing setCenterCoordinate and
setRegion. I am compiling using iOS7.0 but my device has iOS6.1 version. When I am doing pinch in-out, zoom in-out it is crashing. 
I tried running instrument but I do not see any memory issue. All allocation and leaks are properly handled. Please any one know what is the issue?

Code for providing annotation:

```
  NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i =0;i<[mListArr count];i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *theDict = [mListArr objectAtIndex:i];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationCoord;

        annotationCoord.latitude = [[theDict objectForKey:kLatitudeKey] doubleValue];
        annotationCoord.longitude = [[theDict objectForKey:kLongitudeKey] doubleValue];

        MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
        annotation.coordinate = annotationCoord;
        annotation.title = [theDict objectForKey:kAddressKey];
        annotation.subtitle = [theDict objectForKey:kRegionKey];
        [arr addObject:annotation];

    }
    if([arr count]>0)
    {
        [mapView addAnnotations:arr];

        NSDictionary *theDict = [mListArr objectAtIndex:0];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationCoord;

        annotationCoord.latitude = [[theDict objectForKey:kLatitudeKey] doubleValue];
        annotationCoord.longitude = [[theDict objectForKey:kLongitudeKey] doubleValue];

        [mapView setCenterCoordinate:annotationCoord animated:YES];

        MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(annotationCoord, 50000, 50000);
        [mapView setRegion:[mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];

    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I am using ARC.

Edit:
Following is the log:

```
* thread #3: tid = 0x2803, 0x3af605d0 libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent64 + 24, queue = 'com.apple.libdispatch-manager 
frame #0: 0x3af605d0 libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent64 + 24 
frame #1: 0x3ae9bd26 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_invoke + 810 
frame #2: 0x3ae97378 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_thread + 36
```

**Now I am getting following log after running on device:**

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x2403, 0x3791ae46 libGPUSupportMercury.dylib`gpus_ReturnGuiltyForHardwareRestart + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1)
    frame #0: 0x3791ae46 libGPUSupportMercury.dylib`gpus_ReturnGuiltyForHardwareRestart + 10
    frame #1: 0x3791b764 libGPUSupportMercury.dylib`gpusSubmitDataBuffers + 124
    frame #2: 0x330af5e4 IMGSGX543RC2GLDriver`SubmitPacketsIfAny + 244
    frame #3: 0x3550e37a GLEngine`gliPresentViewES + 206
    frame #4: 0x35516df2 OpenGLES`-[EAGLContext presentRenderbuffer:] + 74
    frame #5: 0x39cf8596 VectorKit`-[VGLScreenCanvas didDrawView] + 54
    frame #6: 0x39cf855c VectorKit`-[VKScreenCanvas didDrawView] + 60
    frame #7: 0x39cf84a6 VectorKit`-[VKMapCanvas didDrawView] + 42
    frame #8: 0x39cef838 VectorKit`-[VKScreenCanvas onTimerFired:] + 1124
    frame #9: 0x39ced808 VectorKit`-[VKMapCanvas onTimerFired:] + 500
    frame #10: 0x39cec6a6 VectorKit`-[VKMainLoop displayTimerFired:] + 614
    frame #11: 0x35ca07a8 QuartzCore`CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch(unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 160
    frame #12: 0x35ca0700 QuartzCore`CA::Display::IOMFBDisplayLink::callback(__IOMobileFramebuffer*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, void*) + 64
    frame #13: 0x37f1cfd6 IOMobileFramebuffer`IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 154
    frame #14: 0x34c935ac IOKit`IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 192
    frame #15: 0x3407588a CoreFoundation`__CFMachPortPerform + 118
    frame #16: 0x340803e6 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 34
    frame #17: 0x3408038a CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 138
    frame #18: 0x3407f20e CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1382
    frame #19: 0x33ff223c CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
    frame #20: 0x33ff20c8 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
    frame #21: 0x37bd133a GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 74
    frame #22: 0x35f0e2b8 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1120
    frame #23: 0x00134928 AppName`main(argc=1, argv=0x2fd1fd08) + 116 at main.m:16
    frame #24: 0x3c1d3b20 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: No error message. It shows EXC_BAD_ACCESS in main.

Comment: Use NSZombies to help to know which object you want to access that don't exist (anymore).

Comment: I enabled NSZombie but still getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS in main.

Comment: This should log the reason of the error in the debugguer.

Comment: There is no reason in the debugger.

Comment: @NuzhatZari this log looks too short, are you sure that is whole out

Comment: Yes this is I am getting after typing bt in lldb command prompt.

Comment: What method is this code in (ie. the code that adds the annotations)?  What map view delegate methods have you implemented (eg. regionDidChangeAnimated, viewForAnnotation, etc)?  Please post those delegate methods.

Comment: I have not implemented any delegate method. and this method(adding annotation) I am calling when I receive data from server on main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You should set exception breakpoint in xcode and when app crashes you will get access to lldb console to get backtrace with `bt`, this can be very helpful.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Which step you need to elaborate ?

Comment: I have exception breakpoint. Now how to check which object is causing problem?

Comment: * thread #3: tid = 0x2803, 0x3af605d0 libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent64 + 24, queue = 'com.apple.libdispatch-manager
    frame #0: 0x3af605d0 libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent64 + 24
    frame #1: 0x3ae9bd26 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_invoke + 810
    frame #2: 0x3ae97378 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_thread + 36

Comment: I added, please check.